# Is there a public way to force MPNowPlayingInfoCenter to show disabled 15s fast forward button instead of NextTrack button?

Tags: mpremotecommandcenter

I would like Control Center (via MPNowPlayingInfoCenter) to show in Lock screen the forward 15 seconds / back 15 seconds buttons disabled when Advertisement is going

Current behaviour: prevTrack / nextTrack button (disabled) are show in lock screen when Ad is going.
Expected behaviour: forward 15 seconds / back 15 (disabled) to be shown in lock screen when Ad is going.